What are the restrictions on the number of records for real time manticoresearch indexes?
#1. What are restrictions on the number of records for real time manticoresearch indexes?
#2. What problems can arise with >300kk records?
#3. How will manticore feel when writing to an index with 300kk records  1k records per minute (up to 1kk per day, + these records will be updated within some minutes).
I understand that the final answer can only be obtained from the results of operation on production, but maybe someone has such experience?
P.S.
Server parameters on which this will work:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1271 v3 @ 3.60GHz
RAM 16Gb


Honestly can't really give a proper answer to this. As you say would really have to benchmark to find out. In general sounds fairly small, and managable. Have indexes with millions or rows with lots of updates, on smaller servers. Will spike to 3k updates/minute. The main limiation is typically RAM, you need enough ram, that basically the whole index can be held in ram( although it doesnt actully need to all be stored) - in general 16gb sounds ok - but depends on row length. But also depends on what else the server is doing! Also query volume ma be most important consideration.
